# Turn on Vim plugins for some files, not others?

Tags: vim

I recently added `filetype plugin indent on` to my .vimrc in order to enable special indenting and syntax highlighting for Clojure code (*.clj files).  However, it's also causing indenting in my LaTeX files (*.tex).  This is annoying when I'm editing, and even more annoying, because the tab characters that get inserted confuse a custom program I use to process my LaTeX files.  I know I can make indenting use spaces, but I really just want "intelligent" LaTeX indenting to go away.  Actually, I want all intelligent indenting to go away, except where I specifically ask for it.

How can I get correct auto-formatting for Clojure code in Vim, but turn off all special handling of LaTeX files (except for syntax highlighting)?

Sorry if this has already been answered; I haven't succeeded in finding the answer yet.

(Irrelevant editorial comment: Sometimes Vim "upgrades" make me want to go back to Unix 'vi'.  OK, not really.)

Answer (score 3):

Each proper filetype plugin script has an inclusion guard at its beginning. If you don't want any of the filetype options for Latex files (i.e. filetype of `tex`), create a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` with these contents:

```
:let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

This causes the default ftplugin from `$VIMRUNTIME` to abort its execution. The same applies to indent: `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim` and `b:did_indent` is the guard variable.

#### Alternative

On the other hand, if you just want to undo certain options (e.g. `:setlocal expandtab` to avoid inserting tabs), you'd put those overriding commands into the so-called *after directory*: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`.

Comment: Ingo, thanks very much.  You've saved me many annoying moments. For anyone else reading this, I want to note that merely changing the value of b:did_indent where it appears in an existing indent/tex.vim file isn't enough; it works, though, if `let b:did_indent = 0` appears at the beginning of this file.  Your tip about the `after` directory is also very, very helpful.